# Frameless text field In html page

Tags: html, css, user-interface

is there a JavaScript or css library which hides all the border of a text field and make it look like you are writing on a line?

I don't have an example of it.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/CuR9G/

Comment: why would you need a css library?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use some library. Such result will give content editable span (adding some style to remove border around it while writing):

```
<span contenteditable style="outline:0px solid transparent;" ></span>
```

similar result will give content editable div, however it can be styled better because it is block

```
<div contenteditable style="outline:0px solid transparent;" ></div>
```

It is without borders and you can write anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple css should work

```
<style>
input {
   background-color: #fff; // your doc background color
    border: 0px;
```

outline:none;
    }

Comment: if the content is going to be submitted (form), then I think this option is best.

Comment: You should also consider hiding the outline entity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a good solution is to use @Mark's answer but using a css class:

in CSS:

```
.inline-input {
   background-color: #fff; // your doc background color
   border: 0px;
   display: inline;
}

/*  and if you also don't want the outline when input get focus */
.inline-input:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

in HTML:

```
Some text before <input type="text" class="inline-input" name="xxx"/> some text after
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using chrome the field still highlights when selected, so although there is not a border around the field the square highlight makes it appear as though there is when the field is in focus.